# Test word against array for anagrams - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, anagram

So far.. I have this:

```
function anagrams(word, words) {
  for(let i = 0; i <= words.length; i++){
  const aCharMap = buildCharMap(word);
  const bCharMap = buildCharMap(words[i]);

  if(Object.keys(aCharMap).length !== Object.keys(bCharMap).length) {
    words.pop(words[i])
  }
  for (let char in aCharMap) {
    if (aCharMap[char] !== bCharMap[char]) {
    words.pop(words[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(word);
  console.log(words);
  }
}

  function buildCharMap(str) {
  const charMap = {};
  for (let char of str.replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase()) {
  charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1 || 1;
  }
  return charMap;
}
```

The question at hand is obvious if you read through the code but here it is

Write a function that will find all the anagrams of a word from a list. You will be given two inputs a word and an array with words. You should return an array of all the anagrams or an empty array if there are none. For example:

`anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']) => ['aabb', 'bbaa']`

`anagrams('racer', ['crazer', 'carer', 'racar', 'caers', 'racer']) => ['carer', 'racer']`

`anagrams('laser', ['lazing', 'lazy',  'lacer']) => []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `pop` used the way you use it?

Alternatively you can do like this:

```js
function anagrams(word, words) {
let result = [];
const aCharMap = buildCharMap(word);

// you also had a off-by-one error in loop 
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const bCharMap = buildCharMap(words[i]);

    let isAnagram = (a, b) => {
        if (Object.keys(a).length !== Object.keys(b).length) return false;
        for (let char in a) {
            if (aCharMap[char] !== b[char]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (isAnagram(aCharMap, bCharMap)) result.push(words[i])

}

function buildCharMap(str) {
    const charMap = {};
    for (let char of str.replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase()) {
        charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1 || 1;
    }
    return charMap;
}

return result
}

console.log(anagrams("test", ["estt", "ttee", "tset"]))
```

Comment: pop is a js method on arrays

Comment: This works fabulous and yes I should not have been using those syntax! I am so happy you got it completed the way I had in my mind but I didn't quite know how. I still am in the process of learning these lamdas and the syntaxical rules for returns after booleans are used. I am coming from a heavy Java background